# C Programming: malloc() inside a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, malloc

I would like to allocate memory in a function and then use that space in the main().
All is fine in the function, but I never can access the data in the main().
There are two memory allocation instructions for simulating a two dimensionnal array of chars

**Here's my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getNetworks(char **networks) {

  networks = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));
  printf("networks in function:%p\n", networks);

  networks[0] = (char*) malloc(4);
  strcpy(networks[0], "aaa");
  networks[1] = (char*) malloc(3);
  strcpy(networks[1], "bb");
  networks[2] = (char*) malloc(5);
  strcpy(networks[2], "cccc");
  networks[3] = (char*) malloc(6);
  strcpy(networks[3], "ddddd");
  networks[4] = (char*) malloc(2);
  strcpy(networks[4], "e");
  return 5;
}

int main ()
{
  char **networks = NULL;
  int nbNetworks;

  printf("networks before call:%p\n", networks);
  nbNetworks = getNetworks(&*networks);
  printf("networks after call:%p\n", networks);
  for (int i=0; i<=nbNetworks-1; i++) {
    printf ("%s\n", networks[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Output is**

```
networks before call:0x0
networks in function:0x7feb65c02af0
networks after call:0x0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: That should be `*networks = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));` because you want to modify the parent's variable, not the value parameter on the stack.

Comment: getNetworks(&*networks); smells bad.

Comment: In the same way it should be `(*networks)[0] = (char*) malloc(4);` as you are working with the parent's array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code, I will not comment them, but propose you this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** getNetworks(int *n)
{
  int count = 5;
  char ** networks = malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
  printf("networks in function:%p\n", networks);

  networks[0] = (char*) malloc(4);
  strcpy(networks[0], "aaa");
  networks[1] = (char*) malloc(3);
  strcpy(networks[1], "bb");
  networks[2] = (char*) malloc(5);
  strcpy(networks[2], "cccc");
  networks[3] = (char*) malloc(6);
  strcpy(networks[3], "ddddd");
  networks[4] = (char*) malloc(2);
  strcpy(networks[4], "e");
  *n = count;
  return networks;
}

int main ()
{
  char **networks = NULL;
  int nbNetworks;

  printf("networks before call:%p\n", networks);
  networks = getNetworks(&nbNetworks);
  printf("networks after call:%p\n", networks);
  for (int i=0; i < nbNetworks; i++) {
    printf ("%s\n", networks[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: warning : `malloc(*n * sizeof(char*))`  while `*n` (in fact _nbNetworks_) is non initialized, move `*n = 5;` before (I am not the DV ;-) )

Comment: @bruno Thanks, corrected. I did not execute it, it was a mistake.

Comment: it works. Just a semicolon missing after "int count = 5". Nice solution.

Comment: @Noury ok, happy.  I wrote the code directly in editor, so some bugs were present.

Answer (score 4):

The following needs to be fixed:

```
int getNetworks(char ***networks)
```

as it is a pointer to an array of pointers to chars. (You can also write this as
 `char **networks[]`).

In the function you must first dereference the pointer to work on the parent's variable:

```
    *networks = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));
    (*networks)[0] = (char*) malloc(4);
```

In main, your declaration is correct, however, you must call as:

```
    getNetworks(&networks);
```

so the function can work on the parent's variable.

Comment: This worked right away thanks!